# Should I mention NDS programs I am pursuing in my Masters application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science

I am applying to the GA Tech Online Masters in Computer Science for Fall 19. My undergraduate degree is not in CS, however my minor is and I currently work as a software developer. While the program is receptive to that kind of applicant, I am considering backup plans should I be rejected.

I am currently looking at various non degree seeking options as a way to knock out some additional CS course as a way to show my commitment and strengthen my application should I be rejected for the masters and need to reapply later.

My dilemma is that  I am unsure if I should include the NDS programs in the "other schools you are applying to" section of the masters application. I suppose a sub-dilemma would be the ethics of applying to an NDS program knowing that I would drop it the second I got into a masters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, a "Non Degree Student" program isn't another school you are "applying to", so, in an online application or a form, you probably shouldn't list it as if it were.

But it would be good to find a way to list such things elsewhere if you have the opportunity, such as in a personal statement. Getting more CS instruction will be seen as a positive thing no matter how you go about it.

I also doubt that there is any ethical constraint on you dropping out of any program if things change. There really is no expectation, especially in such a program, that you will complete it, and you leave no-one disadvantaged if you go.

Comment: Thanks! I had a hunch that I was overthinking things, but I'm glad to hear it from someone else.